# Map in Cmake script

Tags: cmake

I'd like to map a variable to a string, as in this example in pseudo-cmake code

```
map(mymap "val1" "key1" "val2" "key2") # <-- this seems not to exist
set(filename "prependfilename${mymap[${avar}]}otherpartoffilename")
```

basically in my case i have to concat the strings "a32" or "a64" on the filename based on the ${ANDROID_ABI} (which is a variable expressing the target architecture type) value.

How to achieve a simple map behaviour for variables in CMake?

Comment: @KamilCuk your 1 min google search fails miserably if a key contains an equal sign, like "o=ne". But I guess that's what happens taking code found on google in 1 min.

Comment: Sure... then patch it? Invent some escaping and write a regex to replace `=` with some unique escape pattern, like `%=` (and replace `%` with `%%`). Then a regex to replace it back. Should handle it.

Comment: @KamilCuk question was more how to handle this problem on Cmake (being something general enough that a solution/workaround had to exist). I find Tsyvarev answer excellent and fully answering the question.

Comment: I tested the library there - it correctly handles `=` in values. `dict(SET mydict a "this=that")
dict(GET mydict a value)
message(STATUS "${value}")` shows `this=that`.

Comment: @KamilCuk not on keys though, being the regex finding the first =.

Comment: I tested the library too just to find a potential pitfall that would make my question look less silly and soothe my ego. ahahahahahahah

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CMake doesn't support `[]` or `{}` operators, but mapping could be achieved by **naming scheme** for a variable:

```
# The naming scheme: mymap_<val>
set(mymap_val1 key1) # Maps val1 => key1
set(mymap_val2 key2) # Maps val2 => key2
# ...
set(avar val1) # Some key
message("Key ${avar} is mapped into: ${mymap_${avar}}")
```

This way for "mapping" is actively used by CMake itself.

E.g. variable [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) maps a programming language to the compiler and variable [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) maps both language and configuration type into the compiler flags, specific for this configuration.